# How would I override the perform_destroy method in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

DRF currently has functionality that throws a 404 if an object doesn't exist in the db.  For example

```
Request: /delete/1234
Response: 204 (success)
Request 2: /delete/1234
Response: 404 (not found)
```

This logic is very problematic for my mobile apps and i would like to change it so that I override the 404-not-found functionality. In other words, I want my request to be idempotent.  For example:

```
Request: /delete/1234
Response: 204 (success)
Request 2: /delete/1234
Response: 204 (success)
```

I've been looking at the docs but i'm not really sure how to override the **`get_object_or_404`** functionality.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe, if there is no object to delete, ideally it should return 404 as DRF does.

For your requirement the following code will do the trick:

```
from rest_framework import status,viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import Http404

 class ExampleDestroyViewset(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
            self.perform_destroy(instance)
        except Http404:
            pass
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 6):

To implement the custom functionality you need to override `get_object()` method in the viewset. Follow the links [get_object](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3e1687282ba39b0166b7c17e39cdd3a2be7e2bc3/rest_framework/generics.py#L49) and [perform_destroy](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L90)

```
class ExampleDestroyViewset(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = # queryset
    serializer_class = # serializer class
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # write custom code

    def perform_destroy(self, instance): 
        # write custom code
```