# How to add a Reason for Deletion to all DRF Delete APIs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

In a Django Rest Framework app using [Django Simple History](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/master/docs/index.rst) to track model changes, how would one force a user to pass a `Reason for Deletion` for all [Destroy End Points](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroymodelmixin) and then pass that reason to Django Simple History's [Change Reason](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#change-reason)?

Also, for related models with a Delete Cascade, would that reason be passed on to the related deleted entries?

**Update:**

Tried overriding the destroy method as below following [another question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529791/1082673). Issue is, where is the changeReason i.e. `history_change_reason` located after the delete? I thought it would be a column in the historical table? However, its not there so even if the code below is working, I can't find where the reason has been saved.

```
class DeleteViewSet(mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if 'delete_reason' not in request.data.keys():
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,data='{delete_reason: Invalid Delete Reason}')
            else:
                instance = self.get_object()
                instance.changeReason = request.data['delete_reason']
                instance.save()
                self.perform_destroy(instance)
        except Http404:
            pass
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**Missing History Change Reason Column:**

The only `history_*` I see in all history tables are:

```
1. history_id
2. history_date
3. history_type
4. history_user_id
```

I can't find `history_change_reason` in any of the history tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the answer to two of my problems.

**Missing History Change Reason Column:**

This was a version issue. `pip3.6 install --upgrade django-simple-history` and then migrate solved this.

**Deletion Reason as a Mixin:**

This works by checking if deletion_reason is provided.

```
class DeleteViewSet(mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if 'delete_reason' not in request.data.keys():
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,data='{delete_reason: Invalid Delete Reason}')
            else:
                instance = self.get_object()
                instance.changeReason = request.data['delete_reason']
                # instance.save()  ==>Don't do this because it will cause a second instance to be saved in the history tables
                self.perform_destroy(instance)
        except Http404:
            pass
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**Not solved:**

Passing the `deletion_reason` to all tables that are subsequently deleted when you have a delete_cascade in the relation between models.