# How to override delete method (generics class) in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to override delete method in generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView class using the followings code snippet. :-

In views.py

```
class ArtistView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer
    queryset = Users.objects.filter(user_type='artist')
```

In serializers.py

```
class ArtistProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('profile_pic_url','cover_pic_url','full_name','genre','location')


class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profiles = ArtistProfileSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields =  ['id','user_type', 'email', 'profiles','username']
        def delete(self, instance, *arg, **kwargs):
            profile = instance.profiles
            profile.delete()
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('all-artist/', views.ArtistListView.as_view()),
path('all-artist/<int:pk>', views.ArtistView.as_view())]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the `delete()` method in the Serializer (and definitely not in the Meta definition).

Delete logic should be handled for you because you derive from `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` in your view.

If you want to add custom logic, then you can override [`perform_destroy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515994/39296) in the view.

- [`RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview)
- [`DestroyModelMixin`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroymodelmixin)